# Comparing two arrays and finding differences

Tags: arrays, algorithm, perl, comparison

I need to compare two array and get differences.

Background:

1st array will list out files in folder.

2nd array will read the content of a file and stored in array.

The output of 1st array will be

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

The output of 2nd array will be

```
a
b
c
e
```

How I can compare those 2 array that get differences? The finale output that I want is

```
d
```

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $list  = "experiment.sv";
my $path  = "../../../folder1/";
my $filelist;

open ( OUTFILE, ">output.txt" );
main ();
close OUTFILE;


sub main {

   my @array1;
   opendir ( DIR, $path ) || die "Error in opening dir $path\n"; 
   while ( $filelist = readdir (DIR) ) {
       next if ( $filelist =~ s/\.//g);   #/
       push @array1, $filelist;         
   }
   closedir(DIR);

   my @array2;
   open( my $fh, "<", "$path/$list") or die "Failed to open file: $!\n";   
   while(<$fh>) { 
      push @array2, $_;                  
   } 
   close $fh;

   my @result;
   foreach my $array2 (@array2) {
       foreach my $array1 (@array1) {
           if ($array1 !~ /$array2/ ) {
               push @result, "$array1\n";
           }
       }
   }

   print OUTFILE "",@result;  

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, also depending on what exactly is needed.

Using an ancillary hash for each array, to reduce the existence check to a lookup

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

sub diff_arys {
    my ($ra1, $ra2) = @_;

    my %in_a1 = map { $_ => 1 } @$ra1;
    my %in_a2 = map { $_ => 1 } @$ra2;

    my @not_in_one = grep { not exists $in_a1{$_} } @$ra2;
    my @not_in_two = grep { not exists $in_a2{$_} } @$ra1;

    return (@not_in_one ? \@not_in_one : undef), 
           (@not_in_two ? \@not_in_two : undef);
}

my @ary1 = 'a'..'e';         # a,b,c,d,e
my @ary2 = ('a'..'d', 'z');  # a,b,c,d, z
    
my ($not_in_one, $not_in_two) = diff_arys(\@ary1, \@ary2);

say "@$not_in_one"  if $not_in_one;
say "@$not_in_two"  if $not_in_two;
```

Prints

```
z
e
```

This finds difference both ways, elements in one array but not in the other. If you know for fact that you only need it for one "direction," to identify things that are in the first array but not in the second (as it seems from the question), then adjust the sub so to only get needed return. Then there's less code, and you can just return the array (so, a list or empty)

Note the choice for the interface: Return `undef` if no difference is found, an arrayref otherwise.

There are good modules for this kind of work. A rather comprehensive one is [List::Compare](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Compare). There are also [Array::Utils](https://metacpan.org/pod/Array::Utils) and [Array::Compare](https://metacpan.org/pod/Array::Compare), and yet more. And then there are more complex tools that can also be used for this, like [Algorithm::Diff](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Diff).

Comment: @daffodil Please describe why it doesn't work for you, and maybe update your question, so people can adjust their answers to what you need.

Comment: @daffodil  How so -- what "doesn't work"?  I just copy-pasted this into a file and ran it, for yet another check, and it works.  Please let me know what it does for you.

Comment: Hi, it already works, this due to my first two array wrongly coded. Great Thanks!

Comment: btw, is there a away for the output to print in new line?

Comment: @daffodil Great that it works :)   What do you mean "in new line"?  Once we have it in arrays can print it any way, can you explain (with an example maybe?) how you want it?

Comment: let say, i have two different element. it will display for eg: z e. how i want it to display z\n e;

Comment: @daffodil Ah, I see.  One way: `say for @ary;`  (short for `say $_ for @ary` which is the same as `for (@ary) { say $_ }`.  That prints each element on its own line (`say` is the same as `print` with newline added, so `say $_` is the same as `print "$_\n"`). Is that what you mean?

Comment: ("_which is the same as..._" in my comment right above isn't quite correct. the "inverted" one, with the [statement modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers), doesn't define a scope and one can only use one statement)

Answer (score 4):

As explained in [`perldoc -q "difference of"`](https://perldoc.pl/perlfaq4#How-do-I-compute-the-difference-of-two-arrays?-How-do-I-compute-the-intersection-of-two-arrays?), you can get the symmetric difference of two arrays like this:

```
my %count;
for my $x (@array1, @array2) {
    $count{$x}++;
}
my @difference;
for my $x (keys %count) {
    if ($count{$x} == 1) {
        push @difference, $x;
    }
}
```

This assumes there are no duplicate elements in either array.

Alternatively, if you only want to find elements of array1 that are not present in array2, you can build a hash from the second array and use that to filter the first array:

```
my %seen;
$seen{$_} = 1 for @array2;
my @missing = grep !$seen{$_}, @array1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my @array1= (qw(a b c d e f g   i  ));
my @array2= (qw(a b c   e   g h i j));

my %missing1, %missing2;

# Create an hash entry (value undef) for every array1 member
@missing1{@array1} = ();
# Delete every array2 member
delete @missing1{@array2};

# and v.v.
@missing2{@array2} = ();
delete @missing2{@array1};

print "Elements of array 1 missing in array 2:\n", Dumper sort keys %missing1;
print "Elements of array 2 missing in array 1:\n", Dumper sort keys %missing2;
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, it doesn't work for me as both of them just print out array 1 and array 2

Comment: Maybe this is because the arrays do not share any elements? Show your code.